# how do I initialize an ArrayList in an FXML controller class?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am creating a gui where it takes in a text file as input, parses it, stores it into an ArrayList and then displays that onto a tableview. Everything is working fine, except I am trying to initialize the tableview so that as soon as the program runs the tableview is filled with data. When I try to initialize the ArrayList I get an error saying theres a syntax error. I guess I can't initialize it in the controller class. So how would I do it then?

Comment: You initialize an `ArrayList` exactly the same way as you do in any other class.

Comment: A ***syntax*** error means you did not write valid java code.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error while initializing an ArrayList means you did not obey the rules of initializing one. You can initialize ArrayList in a controller class or any other Java class for that matter using any of the following syntax:

Method 1:

```
        List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
       colors.add("Red");
       colors.add("Green");
       colors.add("Blue");
```

Method 2:

```
                List<String> colors = Arrays.asList("Red", "Green", "Blue");
```

Method 3:

```
               List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Red", "Green", "Blue"));
```

Method 4:

```
                 List<String> colors = new ArrayList<String>();
                       Collections.addAll(colors,"Red","Green","Blue");
```

Method 5:

```
                 List<String> colors = new  ArrayList<String>() {{

                 add("Red");

                 add("Green");

                  add("Blue");

                   }};
```